# Hypothesis Test on Three proportional data with different sample size

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, trend

I have three proportional data H1, H2, and H3. And my null hypothesis H0 would be H2-H1=H3-H2.
What would be the test statistics here? I tried to use the proportional test for H_0:P2=P1. But the test required the sample size for P2 and P1. So in my case, H1, H2, and H3 all have different sample sizes. What test should I go for it? Or should I use the statistical for trend analysis for it if that works better?